# C++ Lua 5.1 Issue

Tags: c++, lua

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

    int main (void) {
      char buff[256];
      int error;
      lua_State *L = lua_open();   /* opens Lua */
      luaL_openlibs(L);

      while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
        error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "line") ||
                lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
        if (error) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
          lua_pop(L, 1);  /* pop error message from the stack */
        }
      }

      lua_close(L);
      return 0;
    }
```

This seems to propagate several errors such as:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl lua_tolstring(struct lua_State *,int,unsigned int *)" (?lua_tolstring@@YAPBDPAUlua_State@@HPAI@Z) referenced in function _main  main.obj

What's wrong?

Comment: If you're doing C++, then you should include: `/lua-5.1.4/etc/lua.hpp`

Comment: Sorry but where is that in the code you presented above?

Comment: I misread :).  Even so, with #include <lua.hpp>, it errors "code generation fail"

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the lua headers in `extern "C"` to get the correct symbol linkages, as well as linking to the lib(if your not compiling it into the project)

Comment: extern "C"{
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // Like so?  It gets a different error this time, Code Generation Failed.

Comment: @Camoy: What errors accompany the failure? Did you rebuild all to avoid polluted objs?

Answer (score 6):

Lua 5.1 has lua.hpp:

```
// lua.hpp
// Lua header files for C++
// <<extern "C">> not supplied automatically because Lua also compiles as C++

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

Just `#include <lua.hpp>`.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution is not worked for me. Then I double-checked and I was using 32bit binaries in 64bit build, Stupid me. If you also have this issue please double-check,

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this linking error and I Had to change the

```
#define LUA_API extern
```

to

```
#define LUA_API extern "C"
```

I'm using Lua 5.1 BTW

Answer (score 1):

Probably nothing wrong with your code, you have a linking problem, it can't find the function definition for lua_tolstring. Add the lua library when linking and you should be fine.

Comment: I thought I did.  Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies --> lua.lib

Comment: @Camoy - No got Projects & Solutions and add the path in the lib files

Answer (score 0):

The Lua files are in C so you have to use

```
extern "C" { #include "luafiles.cpp" }
```

You are just getting linker errors.