# Link c++ object during runtime?

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, runtime

I'm trying to write my first game in c++, and I want it to dynamically load everything from files. This includes the enemies, and I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically include their code at runtime, instead of linking the on compile, so that the levels are easily interchangeable. Lua might be an option but I have no clue where to start, and dll seems to be Windows-only (and I wouldn't know where to start there anyway). Can anyone help with this?

tl;dr I want to link in code to my c++ game at runtime.

Comment: I got half way through your question and was going to recommend Lua, and then I saw that you are aware of this option. You won't regret this option after going through the pain of getting Lua embedded into your app and deciding how to wrap your c/c++ interfaces (SWIG is great). The payback is worth the effort.

Comment: @Chris Do you have a tutorial I could follow to do that?

Comment: One way would be to use Cygwin or Mingw on Windows, although you can use shared objects (dll equivalents) while programming on Linux. If you're ok with programming in Windows, there's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: @Nav I'm programming in Linux because that's what my dad uses and he'll be able to help me, and I also want it to be cross-platform.

Comment: @Nav Shared objects look interesting, do they work cross-platform?

Comment: Shared objects don't work crossplatform. You could either write #ifdef's for conditional compilation or use something like the QT framework, which would help you write crossplatform code: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=shared+objects+linux+crossplatform%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VGZHU7KSFZPFuATclYC4CQ

Comment: @Aidan Sorry had to run. I do not have a tutorial, I kinda just included the files myself and get the compile to work. There are tutorials all over the web for this. Did not post one as I would not be trying it and do not want to paste bad info... Ill post an answer though with the basic steps I choose for my projects in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Lua approach you first need to choose the version first. Right now there is the major version 5.1 and 5.2. My previous work was using 5.1 and for my new project I decided to update to 5.2, however I found that my favorite script wrapping tool (SWIG) does not work with 5.2. Just something to decide at the beginning, because you do not want to get a version working and then have to change it.

Lua comes with makefile build environment. My first experience of trying to build on Windows was a bit of a nightmare, did not appear to just run out-of-the-box, so I opted to create my own Visual Studio project at the time, and just include all the .C files in the project. There are two files which need to selectively included/excluded depending on how you intend to compile: lua.c and luac.c. If you are planning to embed Lua in your app, then exclude both of these files; they both contain a main() function and are designed to build console apps. Include all the rest of the C files in your project.

You should be able to compile easy from this point.

When you include the headers of Lua, keep in mind that the functions are C functions so if you are including them from C++ you need to wrap the file inclusion inside of: extern "C" {} - example: [C++ Lua 5.1 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951323/c-lua-5-1-issue)

Wrapping your interfaces in another topic and there are lots of resources available. My favorite is SWIG but there are lots of options, including hand coding the conversion of your C/C++ -> LUA -> C/C++ code. Would recommend just focusing on getting the first part working first, get the interpreter embedded so that you can run a "hello, world!" script from Lua inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

So going by your requirement of crossplatform use and dynamic linking, what you're probably looking for is an environment like QT which has QLibrary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675063/453673

But https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88685/why-arent-more-desktop-apps-written-with-qt

MingW is the open-source equivalent for Visual C++, so it can help you writing code for Windows (though if I had a choice, I'd directly use Visual C++). The way dll's are loaded in Windows is [somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674939/cross-platform-dynamic-linking-windows-to-linux) to the way they're loaded in Linux, so you'll be able to write code with `#ifdef`'s to do conditional compilation. I've written one such program a couple of years back.

Answer (score 0):

To load a shared library(always with .so as suffix) under Linux, you could use dlopen(), dlsym() and dlclose()